# Does formatted HTML takes up more space

Tags: html

If one views the source code of http://www.google.com, it's highly minified. Even the html part. I am just wondering if formatted html takes up more space than minified HTML.

All I can think of is, that in formatted html, the characters : spaces, tabs and newline take space. And that is the only scope where html minification can save memory.

Comment: Funny that they don't even put quotes around class names, if there's just one class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your thinking is correct. Removing whitespace and compressing the HTML will result in smaller download sizes.

If you'd like to see test cases for HTML minification, check out [this blog post on Perfection Kills](http://perfectionkills.com/experimenting-with-html-minifier/#field_testing).

Excerpt:

> Original size: 217KB (35.8KB gzipped)
>   Minified size: 206.6KB (34.3KB gzipped)
>   Savings: 10.4KB (1.5KB gzipped)
>
> Minifying home page of amazon.com saves about 10KB with uncompressed
>   document, and only 1.5KB with compressed one.

Comment: although it is worth noting, unless your google, or facebook or amazon, you really are not going to notice the cost differences of minifying your content to any real degree

Comment: It's important to note that the example above only takes into consideration the HTML footprint. Stylesheets and JavaScript should also be treated the same way in production as they are typically much larger than a single HTML page. Add the three up and your savings potential can be shattering, especially for those on slower connections.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen JS and CSS minification is a MUST for sure. My concern was for only the HTML part. There indeed is some (if not a lot) benefit in minifying HTML too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, minifying HTML, CSS, and JavaScript by removing spaces, tabs, newlines, and comments saves on bandwidth cost.

In addition to minifying the HTML, you should also be certain your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript is being GZIP'ed when being sent over the wire for even better performance. For more information about GZIP, read: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

I would also like to add that it is very important to think about bandwidth cost and page speed to any degree this day in age. Mobile web users are on a large upward swing. Even if you are not expecting a large mobile draw from your site, you are doing a disserve to those trying to access your site on their mobile 3G devices by not taking the proper considerations into bandwidth cost and speed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there’s a difference. But for many (most?) websites this difference is not worth thinking about, because (1) the server will probably serve the HTML gzipped anyway, and (2) you don’t have enough pageviews to make the difference substantial. (Google does.)

Comment: First, you cannot be 100% certain your server is just GZIP'ing all non-binary content, so to blindly accept that it is is not the way to think. Secondly, the difference is **always** worth thinking about, especially with the predominance in mobile web. Smaller transfers shave full seconds off load times on devices over 3G.

Comment: Given the Amazon title page example (and that’s a *huge* page) from a nearby answer, the savings would amount to 10 KB off the uncompressed page. Compare that with the total amount of data transferred in order to display the page, or the connection latency.